# How to I get news titles via PowerShell?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am writing a script in PowerShell which should take from one website and write them to TXT file. What I have actually it's creating new TXT file and opening Internet Explorer.

My code:

```
# Create TXT file that containing one title per line
If (Test-Path "$env:USERPROFILE/titles.txt")
{
 Remove-Item "$env:USERPROFILE/titles.txt"
}
New-Item -name "titles.txt" -path "$env:USERPROFILE" -type file

# Create an Internet Explorer com object
$URL        =       "geekweek.pl"
$ie         =       New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible =       $true
$ie.navigate($URL)
$doc        =       $ie.Document

# Download title and save it into TXT file

#$elm       =       $doc.getElementsById("today-article")











#$ta            =       ($URL.AllElements | ? { $_.Class -eq 'tip' } | select innerText)
#$ta = Get-Content ($URL.Links|where href -match '/#aktualnosci/')
#Write-Host $ta
```

I try to get an Id, class and element by part of href (this try allowed in comments). Someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to final my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

```
$URL        =       "geekweek.pl"
$ie         =       New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible =       $true
$ie.navigate($URL)
$doc        =       $ie.Document
$today = $doc.getElementsByName("today-article") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty outertext
```

The output I receive is

```
Temat dnia


Miniaturowy akcelerator cząstek
```

Comment: Unfortunately no - there is error `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` :/

Comment: Thank you @Micky, it is working :) Now I can modificate my script ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for Internet Explorer to load the necessary elements before trying to fetch them. You can use the line: `while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep 1 }` to achieve this after you navigate to the webpage.

Also, you've incorrectly used `getElementsById`, its supposed to be `getElementById` (no 's').

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving IE enough time to load and parse the page.

```
$ie.navigate($URL);
$doc = $ie.Document;
```

What's happening here is you're telling IE to navigate to that page, but that operation is (kind of) asynchronous - the method returns before the page has been loaded. As a result, there is no document to read.

Once you tell IE to navigate, you need to stop your script until it's finished loading.

```
$ie.navigate($URL);
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {
    start-sleep -seconds 1;
}
$doc        =       $ie.Document;
```

[MSDN documentation for ReadyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534361(v=vs.85).aspx)

After you've loaded the page, you can start looking for your title. There is only one element with an ID of `today-article` (by definition, there can be only one element with a given ID), and to get it you need to use `$doc.getElementById('today-article');` (note there's no **s** in the method name). Once you're in that far, it's more DOM tree walking to get to the child of that node that you're looking for.

Make sure you terminate IE when you're finished too. Leaving running processes behind is not OK.